# how to export only two columns from datagridview to txt file in vb.net

Tags: html, sql, vb.net

i want to export only two columns from datagridview in vb.net i use this code but i don't get the result

```
Dim StrExport As String = ""

For Each R As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows

    For Each C As DataGridViewCell In R.Cells
        If Not C.Value Is Nothing Then
            StrExport &= "" & C.Value.ToString & ""
        Else

        End If
    Next

    StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length)
    StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
Next

Dim tw As IO.TextWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(fName)
tw.Write( StrExport )
```

Comment: How does HTML come into play?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: If you don't want to do something for each cell in a row then don't use a `For Each` loop over the `Cells` of that row. That should be obvious if you understand what a `For Each` loop does.  If you want to do something for two specific cells in a row then specify those two cells.

Comment: I see absolutely no SQL here.